# Open Trip Planner 2. Start server from multiple graph.obj file

Tags: graph, opentripplanner

I have otp-2.0.0-rc1-shaded.jar file into **/home/otp/** directory

I have two graph files (with gtfs archives and pbf files) into following directories:

**/home/otp/graphs/ru**

**/home/otp/graphs/ua**

I tried start server with command

**java -Xmx19G -jar otp-2.0.0-rc1-shaded.jar  --load /home/otp/graphs/**
and I have following error

> Unable to load graph, no graph file found: /home/otp/graphs/graph.obj

How can I run server with two routers?

Answer (score 0):

OpenTripPlanner 2 does not allow starting a server with multiples instances of Graph.obj

http://docs.opentripplanner.org/en/v2.0.0/Version-Comparison/